# Jquery Conflict between Mega-Menu and MailChimp form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, mailchimp, megamenu

Here's a conundrum.. I have two elements that I need on a page that won't play nice with each other: a mega-menu (required for the main site navigation) and a simple mailchimp signup form (in the footer).

See them both on this page here:

https://cms.ucd.ie/geary2020/research/

**The problem is that the mailchimp form (in the footer) won't accept submissions unless the following line is removed:**

```
<script>var plugin_path = '/t4cms/';</script>
```

This code is however is needed by the mega-menu, so I have to keep it there.

If I remove the above line - then the mailchimp form will accept submissions BUT the mega-menu is boken!

I have tried reordering the sequence of the .js files - that didn't work.

Also, I have downloaded and stored locally the mailchimp js file: *mc-validate-geary.js* - so I can make any suggested edits directly in this file. I suspect the solution will be found by editing this file.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: I'm totally stuck on this little bug. It would be great if anyone had any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. It turns out there was ANOTHER reference to mailchimp js elsewhere that was causing the conflict. Through analysing the error via console I was able to locate it. Always check the console!